# How to execute multiple query one by one

Tags: postgresql

```
table_1 (id, first_Name, last_Name)

table_2 (id, name, table_1_id)
```

My work is to copy all values of a column from table_1 to table_2 as individual entry. My query is

Query_1:

```
insert into table_2 ( name, table_1_id )  
   select first_Name as name, id as table_1_id from table_1.
```

My other query is

Query_2:

```
insert into table_2 ( name, table_1_id )  
   select last_Name as name, id as table_1_id from table_1.
```

It run pretty good but save all first_name then save all last_name.
my requirement is to run these two queries together and want the result will be like

```
first_Name(whatever) table_1_id (1)

last_Name(whatever) table_1_id(1)

first_Name(whatever) table_1_id(2)

last_Name(whatever) table_1_id(2)
```

Thanks in advance

Note: `table_1_id` is not a foreign key in `table_2`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using an `union all`:

```
INSERT INTO table_2( name, table1_id)
select name, id from
    (
    select first_name as name, id from table_1
    union all
    select last_name as name, id from table_1
    ) A 
    order by id
```

Comment: what do you mean by ordering_col?

Comment: The perpose of the `ordering_col` is to insure that `first_name` comes always before `last_name`

Comment: The order of the insert is irrelevant as rows in a table don't have a sort order anyway. Therefor the `ordering_col` is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try by using [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

```
   WITH cte AS (
    insert into table_2 ( name, table_1_id )  
    select first_Name as name, id as table_1_id from table_1
    )
    insert into table_2 ( name, table_1_id )  
    select last_Name as name, id as table_1_id from table_1
```

and test values by `select * table_2 order by table_1_id`